# Kafka mirror maker behaviour

Tags: apache-kafka

Say, we are having two Datacenters DC1 and DC2. I am mirroring kafka data from DC1 to DC2 using Kafka mirror maker. Only DC1 is active and DC2 will become active once DC1 goes down.

As per my knowledge, both kafka topic and offsets topic will be mirrored to DC2.

For Example, I have produced 100 msgs to T1 in DC1 and around 80 msgs have been mirrored to DC2. In DC1, I have consumed around 90 msgs. Now DC1 goes down and I am consuming from DC2. My consumer request would be to fetch the 91st message. But only 80 msgs have been mirrored. What will happen in this case? Since required offset is not available, whether this will behave with value of auto.offset.reset.

In another case, say I consumed 90 msgs from DC1 but all 100 msgs have been mirrored to DC2. In this case, If I start consuming from DC2, 10 msgs will be duplicated right?

What will happen if offset topic mirroring not completed after successfull processing?

Answer (score 3):

Mirror maker doesn't replicate the offsets.  Both source and destination can have different number of partitions and different offsets.

If you want to ensure exactly once delivery on DC2 and no data loss, you need to have producer and consumer.properties configured properly.

There are valid scenarios, when consumer consumes some record from source but the producer fails to write to destination. In that scenario, if "enable.auto.commit" is set to true, it will periodically commit the offset even if the event wasn't written in destination. So to avoid that, it should be set to false.

Ensure that for no data loss:

In consumer.properties :  `enable.auto.commit=false` is set

In producer, add following properties :

```
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
retries=Int.MaxValue
acks=-1
block.on.buffer.full=true
```

For mirrorMaker, set `--abortOnSendFail`

Here are some best practices for mirror maker.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/79891/kafka-mirror-maker-best-practices.html

In regards to the consumers running on Destination cluster, they don't care how many records are consumed from Source cluster. They have their own consumer_offsets. So at the first run, it starts from 0 offset, and then next run will read from the last offset you consumed.

If you want to read from offset 0, you can always set "**auto.offset.reset**" to "earliest"

Comment: How does the consumer knows from where to consume when consumer started in DC2? Whether this will be based on the property auto.offset.reset.

Comment: @Hemnath : Are you referring to the kafka mirror maker consumer or  regular consumers running on  DC2 to consume from DC2 cluster?

Comment: @Hemnath If there's no consumers of the DC2 topic, then they start from the earliest offsets. As mentioned, the offsets are not replicated. This includes the consumer offsets topic

Comment: @NishuTayal, I am referring to the regular consumers running on DC2 to consume from DC2 cluster.

Comment: @cricket_007, Thankyou

Comment: @Hemnath : okay, so I have updated the answer with the details. Hope that helps....